# I have make installed pcl-1.13.0, however python can't import it

Tags: ubuntu, pcl

I have python3.8 and python3.10.

I installed pcl following the below steps:

https://alwynm.github.io/blog/general/pcl

however It can not be imported by python3 of ros noetic.

How to fix it?

I have installed it on ubuntu 20.04

expecting:

used by python3 in ros noetic environment.

the characters requirement is too mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Create the virtual environment (replace 3.x with your desired Python version and **'env_name'** with your preferred environment name):

bash

```
python3.x -m venv env_name
Activate the virtual environment:
```

bash

```
source env_name/bin/activate
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  however the  make install set runtime  paths to "/usr/local/lib:/opt/ros/noetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" .  It seems that virtual environment  still can not find it.

Comment: I solved the problem finally.  My python3   symlink somehow is messed up with diffferent minor version. After I  recreated the correct   python3 soft link,  fixing the problem.